# Oracle database redo log switch

Tags: oracle, logging

I want to recreate the redo logs of an Oracle database, but I seem to have hit a dead end.

When i call

```
SELECT GROUP#, ARCHIVED, STATUS FROM V$LOG;
```

I get the following

```
 GROUP# ARC STATUS
---------- --- ----------------
     1 NO  CURRENT
     4 YES UNUSED
     3 YES UNUSED
     2 YES UNUSED
```

The thing is, I have to delete the redo log number 1, but can't because #1 is the current redo log. How do I switch between logs?

I have also tried `ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;` , but I get an error saying that the Database is not open. `ORA-01109`. **The database is only mounted** (not in read write mode), and **I cannot open it** due to the redo logs being corrupt. Also, to even mount the database redolog1 from another DB was used. #2,#3 and #4 were recreated successfully because they were not current.

Does anyone have any idea? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error(ORA-01109) indicates that you are trying to perform an operation on a closed database. So, probably, your database instance has been started with only option `mount`, leaving database closed. You simply need to open database and retry `alter system` command:

```
SQL> alter system switch logfile;
alter system switch logfile
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: database not open 


SQL> alter database open;

Database altered.

SQL> alter system switch logfile;

System altered.
```

---

**Edit**

if you are getting this error

> SQL> alter database open; alter database open * ERROR at line 1: 
>   ORA-00305: log 1 of thread 1 inconsistent; belongs to another database
>   ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: '/oradata/DB/PRBT/redo1B.log'
>   ORA-00305: log 1 of thread 1 inconsistent; belongs to another database
>   ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: '/oradata/DB/PRBT/redo1A.log'

while trying to open your database, it's very likely that database ID in the log file and 
database ID in control file do not match. To put it simply, log file from a different database. To bring your database to live you could try the following;

1. Mount your database
2. recover database until cancel
3. Then open database with resetlogs option

Example:

```
SQL> startup mount;
ORACLE instance started.
Database mounted.

SQL> recover database until cancel;
Media recovery complete.

SQL> alter database open resetlogs;

Database altered.
```

Comment: This is the database that a colleague uses. Apparently the redo logs were corrupt or something and the database won't open, it will only mount. If he manually deletes the redo1A.log and redo1B.log files, the database won't even mount because it wants those logs. That's why I need an alternative.

Comment: Here's what i get:SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00305: log 1 of thread 1 inconsistent; belongs to another database
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: '/oradata/DB/PRBT/redo1B.log'
ORA-00305: log 1 of thread 1 inconsistent; belongs to another database
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: '/oradata/DB/PRBT/redo1A.log'

Comment: @robertpas Please edit your question by adding all relevant information. Start from the very beginning. If you cannot open your database it's a different story.

Comment: This is what i get : SQL> recover database until cancel;
ORA-00279: change 1114876731 generated at 08/29/2013 10:42:12 needed for thread
1
ORA-00289: suggestion : /oraarch/PRBT/PRBT_T0001S0000001745R0728067245.ARC
ORA-00280: change 1114876731 for thread 1 is in sequence #1745


Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
/oraarch/PRBT/PRBT_T0001S0000001745R0728067245.ARC
ORA-00308: cannot open archived log  ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
SVR4 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3

Comment: also if i cancel i will get : ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/oradata/DB/PRBT/system01.dbf'


ORA-01112: media recovery not started

Comment: @robertpas Check if archive log file is present. Try to apply archive logs just to up to the time when you lost/changed your online redo log file.

Comment: You are right. That might have fixed it........... but the archive logs were deleted to save some space *facepalm. Thank you for your help anyway